# Creating Like button change onclick

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm trying to have a button that once clicked it remains clicked i.e changes style but im having trouble im aware of :active etc but they only work when holding mouse down on it and reverts back once clicked. Ive tried several methods but none seem to work and ideally wish to have it work without javascript if possible

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you can achieve this without javascript/jQuery. Here is how to do it using jQuery if you like.

---

```
<button onclick="activateButtonStyle(this)" style="background-color:green;">Click Me!</button>
```

---

```
function activateButtonStyle(self) {
    $(self).css('background-color','orange');
};
```

Comment: how would i use this method with Id's as opposed to to the style you have applied

Comment: you mean in css ? you can add a class in activate function like $(self).addClass('orange'); and in your css you will have .orange{background-color:'orange';}

Comment: if i have custom button i have created using Css i wuold want that button to use that css with the use of ID example <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="like-button">Like</button>

Comment: Also, with a radio button, you could make the appearance change purely with CSS using `:before` and `:after` I'd say JavaScript is a better solution here however

Comment: @Daniel you can use your initial styling using id selector like #like-button {background-color:'green'}; but after the click event you cannot use the same #like-button with a different style in css. You can do something like this : $(self).css('background-color','orange');

Comment: @Harvey i will have to try Javascript i was just advised on trying without it initially as it could break parts of website which in turn means stripping it back out or then fixing the issue

Comment: @Daniel Cool. If you find this answer to be working and helpful then do accept it. :)